# Unable to retrieve file information from SharePoint library using Client Object Model

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to read some attributes from a file in SharePoint 2010 library using client object model.
Here is the sample

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

SP.ClientContext clientContext = new SP.ClientContext( "http://path/to/the/site" );
clientContext.Load( clientContext.Web );
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

SP.File spFile = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/TestLibrary/sample.pdf");
clientContext.Load(spFile);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //here we'll catch exception
```

But I am recieving exception.

> A first chance exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Value does not fall within the expected range.` occurs since [Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyserverrelativeurl%28v=office.15%29.aspx) accepts `serverRelativeUrl` parameter in the following format:

```
/Site_Name/SubSite_Name/Library_Name/File_Name
```

Example:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("https://intranet.contoso.com/news"))
{
    var file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/news/Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx");
    ctx.Load(file);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What I just don't understand, is the fact that Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl method works fine with string passed relative to the library, not to the whole server...