# Retrieve File From Sharepoint Library Using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I would like to retrieve a file from a library folder in a Sharepoint teamsite.  I know exactly where the file will be but I don't know the full name of it.

The full URL to the folder is: http://ts/001/API/Asset%20Optimisation%20Interface/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2F001%2FAPI%2FAsset%20Optimisation%20Interface%2FAsset%20Technical%20Data&FolderCTID=0x0120002C707B834A70044986A39A4BCBFE9C6D&View={889C2A16-626B-4FFC-97F7-142AA27522F3}

Within this folder, there are several subfolders and only one file.  The file is an excel file and the name of it will start with 'my file name'.

I have not found how to query the file without using RecursiveAll in my CamlQuery.  Unfortunately, there will be similarly named files in the subfolders that are returned with this that I am not interested in.

Code below:

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://ts/001/API/");
        var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Asset Optimisation Interface");

        CamlQuery qry = new CamlQuery();

        qry.ViewXml = "<View Scope='Recursive'></View>";

        var files = list.GetItems(qry);
        clientContext.Load(files);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file["FileLeafRef"]);
        }
```

The MSDN documentation on CamlQuery seems to be rather light!

Once I have found the file I'm interested in, I would like to download it to a local drive.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Notes**

- I have no control over folder structure or filenames
- Sharepoint 2013
- .Net Framework 4.0
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll 14.0.0.0
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll 14.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by link and explanation below:
[Unable to retrieve file information from SharePoint library using Client Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404570/unable-to-retrieve-file-information-from-sharepoint-library-using-client-object?rq=1)

Relavent snippet:

```
        CamlQuery qry = new CamlQuery();
        qry.ViewXml = "<View></View>";
        qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/001/API/Asset Optimisation Interface/Asset Technical Data/";
```

I hadn't expected that the Server Relative URL was not relative to the location in the ClientContext